# What is the name of this organic compound?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, alcohols, amines

[image: Organic Compound]

The organic compound in question is shown above. This is how I tried to name it:

- Start from the left hanging  $\ce{H_3C}$.
- $\ce{OH}$ gets the number 2 and $\ce{NH_2}$ gets 6. The lowest numbers possible for the functional groups keeping seniority/priority in mind.
- There are two ethyl groups at 3 and 5.

Hence, the compound should be called 6-Amino-3,5-diethylhexan-2-ol.

I tried searching the web to confirm this, but nothing useful showed up.

Is this the correct IUPAC name of this organic compound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The longest chain has 7 carbon atoms. So you would have an ethyl group in carbon 3 and the amino group will be a ramification in carbon 5. I would stand for:

> 5-(aminomethyl)-3-ethylheptan-2-ol